# Is this velocity-time graph paradoxical?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, education

The velocity-time graph for the free-fall and rise of a body after hitting ground is given as:- [image]

In this diagram, at $t = 5$ units, the velocity has every value between $5$ and $-5$ at the same time.

This diagram is certainly wrong? So, why is this taught in school?

Comment: This is a reasonable question and reasonable thought behind it. What goes on during a collision can be complex, and is left out of beginning physics courses. Problems in these classes look at the velocity before and after. They may well treat a collision as instantly changing the velocity. Seeing that something is wrong with that explanation and wondering what is right is a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be so adamant on asserting that something is wrong with this little.

It really just means that it looks very vertical because the time taken for it to change from $+5\,\text{m/s}$ to $-5\,\text{m/s}$ is very short, so that the slope is almost vertical.

It is a tremendously good approximation of what is really happening.

Answer (score 2):

Infinitely rigid bodies are nonphysical. Discontinuous velocity on collision is a nonphysical consequence of the nonphysical assumption that the colliding bodies are infinitely rigid. Real-life collisions, even of very rigid substances like solid pieces of hardened steel, involve deformation. When elastic bodies collide with deformation, the change of shape corresponds to movement of the center of mass, just as your center of mass gets lower when you change shape by sitting down. The center of mass is accelerated over finite distance and time, to zero velocity at the point of maximum deformation, then up to close to the original speed (minus some energy which is lost to oscillation, heat, sound, etc) in the opposite direction as the body returns to its equilibrium shape.

Introductory physics classes often make nonphysical assumptions in order to simplify problems or isolate concepts. Maybe it would be better if these were made explicitly in footnotes, but doing so would take up a lot of space and might add more confusion than educational value.